# Generic prolog cryptarithmetic program

Tags: prolog, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I'm trying to write a program to solve general cryptarithmetic puzzles such as AM+PM=DAY, SEND+MORE=MONEY..

The program I've written is:

```
gsolve([H1,T1],[H2|T2],[H3|T3]):-
    gsolvehelper([H1,T1],[H2|T2],[H3|T3],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],0).

gsolvehelper([H1,T1],[H2|T2],[H3|T3],D,C):-
    (   var(H1)->select(H1,D,D1);D1=D),
    (   var(H2)->select(H2,D1,D2);D2=D1),
    (   X1 is H1+H2+C),
    (   H3 is mod(X1,10)),
    (   C1 is X1//10),
    gsolvehelper(T1,T2,T3,D2,C1).
```

The input is of the form:

```
gsolve([A,M],[P,M],[D,A,Y]).
```

The head of the first two lists is added to the carry to find the head of the third list and the new carry and so on.

The error I get is:

```
ERROR: is/2: Type error: `[]' expected, found `[2,_G3922]' ("x" must hold one character)
```

I cannot figure out what this error is. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: The code you're showing doesn't give that error message. It gives `'.'/2: ... [_Gxxxx]`, not `is/2: ...[2,_Gxxxx]`, which probably means you have a malformed list construct occurring (the actual list predicate is `'.'`, so `[H|T]` is really `'.'(H,T)` in Prolog).

Comment: I do get the same error message as usb (using SWI7).

Comment: @false You are correct, I should have properly tested this before making the claim: my bad. Since lurker is not getting this error, do you know how this behaves over the various Prologs?

Comment: SICStus, GNU, B, YAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you report is due to what is probably a typo: `[H1,T1]`, appearing in several places. Due to this typo `H2` gets -- unintentionally -- instantiated to a list, causing problems in the summation statement. The following reproduces the error in SWI7:

```
?- X is 1 + [1,_] + 3.
ERROR: is/2: Type error: `[]' expected, found `[1,_G11068]' (a list) ("x" must hold one character)
```

There are other ways in which you can improve your code:

- Since you simply pass on the arguments of `gsolve/3` you do not need to use the head/tail-notation `[H|T]` here.
- You can simply name your second predicate `gsolve/5`, as it is already different from `gsolve/3` due to its arity.
- Several brackets in `bsolve/5` are superfluous. Spacing around the if/then operators can be improved as well.
- Using the combination of `mod/2` and `///2` may introduce problems since the rounding of `///2` (i.e., towards zero, typically at least...) is not consistent with `mod/2`. Use `div/2` (rounding towards negative infinity) instead.

Making alterations based upon the above I get:

```
gsolve(L1, L2, L3):-
  gsolve(L1, L2, L3, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 0).

gsolve([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [H3|T3], D, C):-
  (   var(H1)
  ->  select(H1, D, D1)
  ;   D1 = D
  ),
  (   var(H2)
  ->  select(H2, D1, D2)
  ;   D2=D1
  ),
  X1 is H1 + H2 + C,
  H3 is mod(X1, 10),
  C1 is div(X1, 10),
  gsolve(T1, T2, T3, D2, C1).
```

This does not solve the puzzle yet... However, since it solves the error you mentioned -- and some other things as well -- you should be able to take it on from here.